# How do you retrieve Product information from a Stripe Subscription object in c#?

Tags: c#, stripe-payments

I can fetch a Subscription object from Stripe, but I need to retrieve the ProductID it contains, and I don't know how to parse the object to get it.  The Stripe docs are kinda confusing on this.  I would appreciate any help.  I am using C#.

I fetch the Subscription using this code in a function that returns a Stripe.Subscription object:

```
 var service = new SubscriptionService();
 return service.Get(subscriptionID);
```

Once I get the Subscription object back, how do I parse it in C# to get to the ProductID?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you call your function, you should already have a Subscription object with an array of items (stand for Subscription Item) inside. Within each item you should have the Price object inside, with its Product Id. [Here is the Subscription object structure down to ProductId](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/object#subscription_object-items-data-price-product). You will just need to loop through `subscription.Items` and get `Item.Price.Product`.

Comment: Basically items is a reserved keyword in python so subs['items'].data[0].id will work and subs.items.data[0].id won't. Unfortunately, this is not mentioned clearly in offical stripe documentation.